# How can I keep a list of recently seen users without running out of RAM/crashing my DB?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, time, authentication

Here's some code that should demonstrate what I'm trying to do:

```
current_time  = datetime.datetime.now()
recently_seen = []

user_id = 10

while True:
    if user_id not in recently_seen:
        recently_seen[user_id] = current_time

        print 'seen {0}'.format(user_id)
    else:
        if current_time - recently_seen[user_id] > '5 seconds':
            recently_seen[user_id] = current_time

            print 'seen {0}'.format(user_id)

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Basically, my program is listening on a socket for users. This is wrapped in a loop that spits out `user_ids` as it sees them. This means, I'm seeing user_ids every few milliseconds.

What I'm trying to do is log the users it sees and at what times. Saying it saw a user at 0.1 seconds and then again at 0.7 seconds is silly. So I want to implement a 5 second buffer.

It should find a user and, if the user hasn't been seen within 5 seconds, log them to a database.

The two solutions I've come up with is:

1) Keep the user_id in a dictionary (similar to the sample code above) and check against this. The problem is, if it's running for a few days and continues finding new users, this will eventually use up my RAM
2) Log them to a database and check against that. The problem with this is, it finds users every few milliseconds. I don't want to read the database every few milliseconds...

I need some way of creating a list of limited size. That limit would be 5 seconds. Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the user from your dictionary once you log them to the database?

Comment: I... hadn't considered that ._.

Comment: Ok, I just realised why this won't work. If I log the user to the database and delete it from the dictionary, I'll have nothing to check the 'last seen time' against the next time it's seen (a few milliseconds later).

Comment: Change this section: else:
        if current_time - recently_seen[user_id] > '5 seconds':
            recently_seen[user_id] = current_time

            print 'seen {0}'.format(user_id) to just remove users from your list. Next time they're added to the list, they'll also get logged. Then they won't be logged for 5 seconds, they'll get removed, and, when you see them again, they get added and logged.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using a [DBM](http://docs.python.org/library/anydbm.html)?
It will work like a dictionary but will be stored on the disk.